# Errors When Formatting Code In Python

Tags: python, formatting, indentation

I know this is probably quite a simple problem but I am having an issue with the formatting of my function. I am getting a lot of 'unexpected indent' and also 'unexpected token'. I keep trying to format the function correctly but I have no idea why these errors keep on appearing. Here is my function:

```
def stringCheck(stringForCheck, letterOrNumber):

    valid = True

    x = 0

    a = int(ord(stringForCheck)

    length = len(stringForCheck)

        if LetterOrNumber == 'Letter':

            lowerBoundary = 65

            upperBoundary = 90

        elif LetterOrNumber == 'Number':

            lowerBoundary = 48

            upperBoundary = 57

        while valid == True and x < length:

            if a < lowerBoundary or a > upperBoundary:

                valid = False

            else:

                valid = True

        x = x + 1

    stringCheck = valid



stringCheck('2','Number')
```

Comment: First of all what is your text editor? Use nano or vim when you are writing Python. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

Comment: Hi, I am currently using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Hmm. Use Atom then: https://atom.io And could you share the debug output. Unexpected Token for which line?

Comment: There's missing a closing bracket here: `a = int(ord(stringForCheck)`

Comment: @Christoph Correct +1

Comment: @mertyildiran And here is `unexpected indent` begin at  `if LetterOrNumber == 'Letter':`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I will try using atom.io to see whether the code formatting will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove the unnecessary blank lines
2. You are missing a closing bracket here: `a = int(ord(stringForCheck)`
3. From the line `if LetterOrNumber == 'Letter':` to your `while` loop the lines have one indentation level too much.

After fixing the code it should look something like this:

```
def stringCheck(stringForCheck, letterOrNumber):
    valid = True
    x = 0
    a = int(ord(stringForCheck))
    length = len(stringForCheck)

    if LetterOrNumber == 'Letter':
        lowerBoundary = 65
        upperBoundary = 90
    elif LetterOrNumber == 'Number':
        lowerBoundary = 48
        upperBoundary = 57

    while valid is True and x < length:
        if a < lowerBoundary or a > upperBoundary:
            valid = False
        else:
            valid = True

    x = x + 1
    stringCheck = valid

stringCheck('2', 'Number')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a close bracket after the line

```
    a = int(ord(stringForCheck))
```